Quantum energy teleportation applications
What can be the applications of quantum energy teleportation? There is a lot of talk about this phenomenon, but I fail to figure out what would be the consequences.
Particularly:

Would it allow to do remote energy transfer to the spacecraft or other planets?
Could it replace power grids or high-voltage lines here on Earth?
Or it would be useful only in quantum computers?
Would energy be able to be transferred over quantum internet?
Can it be used to create exotic matter with negative mass?

Are there any other possible applications of QET?

Does random number generation count?

Quantum teleportation requires that we bring the mystery box the old-fashioned way to the destination, i.e. one cannot teleport anything to a place one has never been to? Further, the maximum teleportable energy is limited to the number of boxes we bring to the destination, so bringing just 10 electrons will yield a maximum of 10 electron energy states' worth of teleported energy?

Note that quantum energy teleportation is mainstream physics and has been demonstrated, albeit on a very small scale - see https://www.quantamagazine.org/physicists-use-quantum-mechanics-to-pull-energy-out-of-nothing-20230222/

@gandalf61 An incorrect close reason does not mean the question needs to be reopened. You can select another reason in the "Leave Closed" menu in the reopen queue. There is no need to reopen and reclose it.

@VincentThacker But I don't think the question should be closed at all. In  fact I have just voted to leave it open.

@gandalf61 Well, your opinion is clearly different from the obvious fact that the question needs more focus, which is agreed upon by majority of the community (and moderator(s)).

@VincentThacker (a) Since the "majority of the community" have not expressed their view, I don't see how you can know what they think.; (b) "Question needs more focus" is a matter of opinion, not an "obvious fact".

@gandalf61 There are more than 5 questions in the post all asking about completely different things. The site policy is that there should only be one specific question per post. That is the obvious fact. You can always ask on the meta if you don't understand what I said and want others to explain this even more clearly to you. See the comment https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14816/why-this-question-of-mine-was-closed-it-is-not-mainstream-physics#comment57383_14816.

@gandalf61 I disagree with your assessment of the science. From your Quanta reference: “The incessant vacuum fluctuations cannot be used to power a perpetual motion machine, say, because the fluctuations at a given location are completely random. If you imagine hooking up a fanciful quantum battery to the vacuum, half the fluctuations would charge the device while the other half would drain it.” This is precisely equivalent to what I say in my answer and related comments. The question presupposes science that currently doesn’t exist. No matter which rule it crosses, closing is a good choice.

@VincentThacker the 4 options of the 5 are the same thing worded in a different way.

@DrChinese quantum energy teleportation is not perpetual motion machine.

Although there are a number of theoretical papers on Quantum Energy Teleportation, and perhaps a few experimental studies, this is not something that is remotely close to having any of the applications you mention.  Here is a reference to start on:
Quantum Energy Teleportation: An Introductory Review
The reason is that while energy itself might be able to be teleported, you cannot control the direction of teleportation.  You are just as likely to teleport from location A to B as it is from B to A.  That is true whether you are attempting to teleport information or energy. Note that the timing/ordering of operations during teleportation is never an issue.
Obviously, there is not much application for teleportation if you can't specify the source and the destination.  Your net transfers would always be close to zero.

Hmm, I never heard this to be an issue with quantum teleportation.

Can you please point where in the linked paper this is said?

@Anixx Let's start with a pair of systems A and B in a known total energy state E where A and B are entangled and you expect E(A)=E(B). Then you separate A and B. If you measure A and get energy=E(A), then later measure B and get E(B), you already knew E(B)=E-E(A). But there is no particular requirement EA)<E(B). You'd need that to get any useful effect. Note that in some versions of QET, there is classical communication of information with the intent of conveying whether E(B) is expected to be more or less than E(A). But I haven't seen any useful method to take advantage of this information.

As far as I know, in all versions of QET there is classical communication.

@Anixx Not sure Hotta says this. However, in the 15+ years of papers from Hotta and more by Ikeda: No one has successfully transferred more energy than lost. At least, not that I've seen.

@Anixx A little thought will show that a classical information channel is not likely to lead to net energy transfer. My point is not that there will never be positive quantum energy transfer. My point is that there is no generally accepted theory or experiment showing it at this time.  We deal in generally accepted science here, which is the theory I have presented and that pretty much anyone would agree with. The work of Hotta et al is currently considered speculative. Despite what you say in your OP, there is not a "lot of talk" about QET. I would say more like deafeningly quiet.

I also never heared about quantum information teleportation that you cannot choose the direction. Where this claim comes from?

@Anixx There is no information being teleported, it’s an unknown quantum state. Similarly, energy - in the normal sense of the word - cannot be teleported.  This is basic theory, from conservation rules.

Your statement contradicts the papers on the subject. But it you are sure, I would suggest to amend this answer with this statement.
